# sort a specific column of date and get the earliest date

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

Need help to sort 4th column from below output and report only the entry with earliest date.

Current Output:

```
Node_name:ABCD Lastacc  :2017-01-05 Info     :testing *Endtime  :2016-12-11* Type     :Exist
Node_name:ABCD Lastacc  :2017-01-05 Info     :testing *Endtime  :2016-12-11* Type     :Exist
Node_name:ABCD Lastacc  :2017-01-05 Info     :testing *Endtime  :2016-12-15* Type     :Exist
```

Expected Output:

```
Node_name:ABCD Lastacc  :2017-01-05 Info     :testing *Endtime  :2016-12-15* Type     :Exist
```

Comment: which one is your **fourth** column? Edit your question and add more detail

Answer (score 1):

`sort -k7 -r your_file.log | head -n 1`

`-k7`: As your example output is separated by spaces in bash, it has to be sorted by the seventh column (`:2016-12-11`).

`-r`: reverses the output, so the latest (=newest) date is in the first line. Remove it if you really are interested earliest (=oldest) date.

Answer (score 0):

Below  will sort in ascending order and will grep the last line of the file

sort -k3 your file|tail -n 1

Answer (score 0):

Solutions based on sorting and taking the first/last line (depending on sort order) will work.

If you have a lot of data, sorting is more computationally intensive that what is required : since you only want the newest line, you can simply parse every line, scan the whole file, and keep the newest in memory (no need to sort the others).

It can be done like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
data_file="data_file"
regex="Endtime :([0-9-]+)"
while IFS= read -r line
do
  [[ $line =~ $regex ]] || continue
  match="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  [[ "$match" < "$newest" ]] || { newest="$match" ; newest_line="$line" ; }
done <"$data_file"
echo "$newest_line"
```

It is very likely that, for your specific case, the one-liner `sort/cut` solution is plenty fast enough, and in this case shorter is better, but on a one-billion line file, there will be a huge performance difference by selecting the proper algorithme.

Please note that the regular expression used to read dates is crude and assumes dates will all be in the same, valid format (which allows direct comparison without further parsing).  One may prefer changing that expression to more carefully match a YYYY-MM-AA format.